# PHP calculate age with birthtime (Y-m-d\TH:i:sO)

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I'm trying to calculate an age in php, but just want to increase the age if the birthtime is also reached, not only the birthday date. Here is what I got so far:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO");
$bday = "1987-01-01T15:30:00+0200";
$diff = abs(strtotime($bday) - strtotime($today));
$age = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
```

It works if the day is reached, but is not time-sensitive. I appreciate any help!

Comment: uh, why convert your time values to strings, then convert the strings BACK to time values? `$diff = abs(time() - strtotime($bday))`. and it's not time sensitive since you only have day-based math going on in there.

Comment: Also, check out http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php. Using the DateTime class may be safer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 # object oriented
    $from = new DateTime('1987-01-01 T15:30:00+0200');
    $to   = new DateTime('today');
    echo 'Years '.$from->diff($to)->y; echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Month '.$from->diff($to)->m; echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Days '.$from->diff($to)->d; echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Hours '.$from->diff($to)->h; echo '<br/>';

    # procedural
    echo date_diff(date_create('1987-01-01 T15:30:00+0200'), date_create('today'))->y;


<?php

//Convert to date
$datestr="2015-06-11 19:10:18";//Your date
$date=strtotime($datestr);//Converted to a PHP date (a second count)

//Calculate difference
$diff=$date-time();//time returns current time in seconds
$days=floor($diff/(60*60*24));//seconds/minute*minutes/hour*hours/day)
$hours=round(($diff-$days*60*60*24)/(60*60));

//Report
echo "$days days $hours hours remain<br />";
?>
```

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't seems to be time-sensitive too. for example, if I set $from to the actual date and playing a bit with the times, nothing changes.

Comment: you want to calculate time too

Comment: thanks again for your help! But I meant it in a slightly different way: for example, today is my birthday and it's early in the morning. Imagine I was born in the evening. I want the year to switch only when the evening is reached, not only the birthday itself.